# find() method getting time to search- c++

Tags: c++, windows, stl

```
map<int, GCCollectedInfo*>::iterator it_cltd = m_gcColtedInfoMap->find(locatn);
if (it_cltd != m_gcColtedInfoMap->end())
{        
    vector<ObjectID>::iterator findIter = find(it_cltd->second->m_gcCollectedlist2->begin(), it_cltd->second->m_gcCollectedlist2->end(), objectID);

    if (findIter != it_cltd->second->m_gcCollectedlist2->end())
     {}
}
```

I write this line of code in my callback method,Probably my vector size is 50000(more or less) . When i am trying to use this code in my application getting more time to load ,which is more than 20 seconds than normal. Is there any alternate way to find an element in vector or list?

Comment: Is the data sorted?

Comment: Are you tied to vector or list? Can you change it to something different?

Comment: Searching in vector is slow ( O(n) ). So you search twice in a not very small vector. I don't know the complexity of your equal operator neither.
To improve speed, use another container if possible, like unordered_map

Comment: @acraig5075 No. The data stored in unsorted format.

Comment: @KjMag i used vector in my code. In which stl library better in this case?

Comment: @AdrianMaire let me try with unordered_map.

Comment: @Dubai: You might discover that inserting in `unordered_map` seem slow, in that case, you could `reserve` a big enough chunk of space before to start inserting/emplace, that usually helps. If you hash is good enough, searching is close to O(k), the best possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the find is regular for each 50000  then better to sort and use std::binary_search